# Help with understand the following inequality steps.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-progressions

Given the following inequality:

$$
\begin{align}
n&\ge1+(t-1)\sum_{i=1}^h 2t^{i-1}\\
&=1+2(t-1)\left(\frac{t^h-1}{t-1}\right)\\
&=2t^h-1
\end{align}
$$

It's not clear to me how the first line gets simplified to the second, mainly the $\left(\frac{t^h-1}{t-1}\right)$ part?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Related_formulas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t \not =1;$

$S_m:= \sum_{i=1}^{m}t^{i-1}=$

$=         1 + t+t^2+.........t^{m-1};$

$tS_m= t+t^2+.......+t^{m-1} + t^m.$

Hence :

$tS_m- S_m =(t-1)S_m= t^m-1;$

$S_m = \dfrac{t^m-1}{t-1}.$

Comment: Nice derivation Peter!

Comment: Gimusi.Thanks, Peter